# Solve Differential equation by using Fourier transform.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

I encountered an exercise in Lars Hörmander's book "The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I". The exercise asks to prove the differential operator $L$ defined below is surjective on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, or, equivalently, to solve the following differential equation:
$$ Lf = xf(x) + f^\prime(x) = g, \forall g \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}), $$
where $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Schwartz space.

The original statement of this is about multivariate functions, but I do believe the essence lays in the one variable case already. What we can observe is that the differential operator $L$ commutes with the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ up to $i$ i.e. $\mathcal{F}(Lf) = iL(\mathcal{F}(f))$. But I don't know how to do the next.

Any comments or solutions will be very much appreciated!

Comment: If I were you, I would simply explicit a Green function.

Comment: Note that that relation implies that if $\xi$ is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform, then $L\xi$ is also an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform (though with a different eigenvalue).

Comment: @Abezhiko Thanks for your comment, but I'm not that familiar with green function theory, would you like to say something more about it?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yeah I also noticed this. However I don't really know how to use this fact since $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ does not have a basis in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ sense. Or do I miss something?

Comment: The observation that $\mathcal FL\phi=\mathrm iL\mathcal F\phi$ is completely irrelevant, as far as I can tell. It doesn't help us solve the problem at all. Starting with our ODE
$$\phi'(x)+x~\phi(x)=g(x)$$
You can just solve it directly with an integrating factor, i.e
$$\phi(x)=\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\int_1^x\mathrm e^{s^2/2}g(s)\mathrm ds+c_1\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}$$

I suppose that you can show this function is Schwarz directly under the presumption that $g$ is Schwarz as well.

Comment: @xxyshz There are a number of bases of $L^2$ that are entirely within $\mathcal{S}$. Since $\mathcal {S}\subset L^2$, they are a basis for $\mathcal {S}$ as well. You will need to show that after applying the inverse of $L$ to $g$ in this basis the result is still in $\mathcal{S}$, but that's not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

### **Showing the existence of a solution.**

Write

$$\phi'(x)=F(x,\phi(x))\tag 1$$
Where
$$F(p,q)=g(p)-pq$$
With some initial condition, say $\phi(0)=1$. If $g$ is Schwarz, then it is continuous, and therefore $F$ is continuous in its first argument. Because $F$ is simply linear in its second argument, it is therefore [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) in its second argument and therefore by the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ s.t a solution to $(1)$ exists in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$.

Following the formalism established in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem#Optimization_of_the_solution%27s_interval), the optimal $\epsilon$ is found to be
$$\epsilon_{\text{opt}}=\min\left(a,\frac{b}{M}\right)$$
Here $M=\Vert F\Vert_\infty=\sup |F|$ and
$a,b$ represent the domain of values for which $F$ is defined in its first and second arguments respectively, i.e
$$\operatorname{dom}F(\cdot,q)=(0-a,0+a) \\ \operatorname{dom}F(p,\cdot)=(0-b,0+b)$$

Since $g$ is Schwarz, it is defined on all of $\mathbb R$, and hence $a=\infty$. Since $F$ is linear in its second argument clearly $b=\infty$ as well and thus $\epsilon_{\text{opt}}=\infty$, i.e the solution for $\phi$ exists on all of $\mathbb R$.

So far, we have found that

- A solution $\phi$ to $(1)$ exists
- $\phi$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R$

---

### **Showing that the solution is Schwarz.**

Again return to $(1)$.

$$\phi'(x)=g(x)-x~\phi(x)$$
Because $g$ is Schwarz, we know that $g(x)\to 0$ rapidly as $x\to \pm \infty$. This means that for large $x$, we know that
$$\phi'(x)\approxeq -x~\phi(x) \\ \text{as}~x\to\pm\infty$$
Which, along with the initial condition, implies
$$\phi(x)\approxeq \exp(-x^2/2) \\ \text{as}~x\to\pm\infty$$

So defining $\Vert \phi\Vert_{m,n}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} |x^m \phi^{(n)}(x)|$ then we can at least be confident that $\Vert\phi\Vert_{m,0}<\infty$.

Now, we can have a look at the $n=1$ case,
$$x^m\phi'(x)=x^mg(x)-x^{m+1}\phi(x) \\ \Vert\phi\Vert_{m,1}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m\phi'(x)|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m g(x)-x^{m+1}\phi(x)|$$
Clearly, by the triangle inequality
$$|x^m g(x)-x^{m+1}\phi(x)|\leq |x^m g(x)|+|x^{m+1}\phi(x)|$$
Hence
$$\Vert\phi\Vert_{m,1}\leq \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^mg(x)|+\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^{m+1}\phi(x)|=\Vert g\Vert_{m,0}+\Vert\phi\Vert_{m+1,0}<\infty$$
Since $g$ is Schwarz and by the previously established result for the $n=1$ case.

How do we continue this for $n=2,3,4,\dots$ etc? Well, taking derivatives of $(1)$, see that
$$x^m\phi^{(n+1)}(x)=x^m g^{(n)}(x)-x^m\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}(x~\phi(x))\tag{2}$$

I'll let you check for yourself (induction) that
$$\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}(x~\phi(x))=n\phi^{(n-1)}(x)+x~\phi^{(n)}(x)$$

Therefore $(2)$ is just
$$x^m\phi^{(n+1)}(x)=x^m g^{(n)}(x)-nx^m\phi^{(n-1)}(x)-x^{m+1}\phi^{(n)}(x)$$

Hence

$$\Vert\phi\Vert_{m,n+1}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m\phi^{(n+1)}(x)|=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m g^{(n)}(x)-nx^m\phi^{(n-1)}(x)-x^{m+1}\phi^{(n)}(x)| \\ \leq \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^m g^{(n)}(x)|+\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|nx^m\phi^{(n-1)}(x)|+\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|x^{m+1}\phi^{(n)}(x)| \\ \implies \Vert\phi\Vert_{m,n+1}\leq \Vert g\Vert_{m,n}+n\Vert\phi \Vert_{m,n-1}+\Vert\phi\Vert_{m+1,n}$$

Therefore the rest of the needed constants $\Vert\phi\Vert_{m,2},\Vert\phi\Vert_{m,3},\dots$ are all finite by induction, and hence $\phi$ is Schwarz.

With these two points is established,

- A solution to $L\phi=g$ exists $\forall g\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$,
- The solution $\phi$ is Schwarz, i.e $\phi\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$,

We have shown that $L$ is surjective on $\mathcal S(\mathbb  R)$.

QED. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Maybe not the solution that Hormander intended, in hindsight.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the existence looks pretty elegant. However, as you pointed out, it might not be the one that Hormander wanted since in the hint he said "observe $\mathcal{F}(L(f))= iL(\mathcal{F}(f))$, then solve the equation explicitly". But thank you very much again!

Comment: @xxyshz Oh yes, very silly of me... Taking the Fourier transform of the equation will leave you with an algebraic equation that you can just solve.

Comment: Yeah, but still, how to do that? Since $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is not finite dimensional, I didn't come up with a simple argument...

Comment: @K.defaoite Doesn't the $xf(x)$ term transform to a $F'(x)$ term in Fourier space, making the equation still differential?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes that's the key point: after Fourier transform, it's still a differential equation and Fourier transform makes it somehow symmetric.